# How to get rid of slow SEHExceptions that are indeed correctly handled in debug mode?

Tags: c++-cli

My application must call a native third-party DLL. For this, I wrote a proxy DLL in C++/CLI that delegates calls to the unmanaged DLL and marshals the result. The vendor of the DLL decided to throw an exception when a value in his unmanaged object is undefined and it is queried. I don't want to use exceptions for flow control so I wrap that into a `Nullable` like this:

```
Nullable<int> NativeThirdPartyThingProxy::SomePropThatMayBeUndefined::get() {
    try {
        return Nullable<int>(_thirdPartyThingRef->getPropThatThrowsException());
    } catch (ThirdParty::UndefinedValueException) {
        return Nullable<int>();
    }
}
```

This works fine - On the C# side, I get a `int?` when I do `var foo = proxy.SomePropThatMayBeUndefined;`.

However, in debug mode (i.e. when running unit tests) this exception is still logged to the console by the debugger, and since the third party DLL does a lot of this exception-throwing thing and I have to query a lot of properties, I see a lot of

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException' in NativeThirdPartyThingProxy.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException' in NativeThirdPartyThingProxy.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException' in NativeThirdPartyThingProxy.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException' in NativeThirdPartyThingProxy.dll
... many many more
```

and execution is slow.

Is it possible to disable these `SEHExceptions` from being shown and speed this up?

Comment: You don't have that many options beyond a telephone.  Right-click the Output window and untick "Exception messages".  Well, one option.

Comment: Yes, I already feared that. I'll have to make do - at least in release mode it is fast enough and there are no messages like this.